# YUI, sync many objects

Tags: model, synchronization, yui

I am evaluating YUI's [model syncing framework](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/model/#model-sync-layers). If I understand correctly, it is designed so that each model synchronizes with server by itself.

In my case, though, I'll probably have up to a hundred of distinct objects of different types (it's a complex web application). I don't want to spawn 100 distinct requests to retrieve their data one by one—I'd like to be able to aggregate requests and send them in a single request to save time and bandwidth.

How should I design my code to make this possible with YUI models?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement a sync for ModelList, rather than Model.

You might want to take a look at the example ["GitHub Contributors" app](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/app/app-contributors.html), which can load data representing multiple GitHub repos in a single call. Or look at the code for the more generic [ModelSync.REST](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/api/modules/model-sync-rest.html) object, which can load data for multiple Models using a single request from a ModelList. In fact, if you're talking to a REST API, you might be able to use ModelSync.REST as-is.

Comment: If I understand correctly, this requires all my models (of different types) to be on a single list, right?

Comment: You do not need to have all models at all times in the list. You can choose to only populate the list with the models required for the app to work. And the list cares not for what type of model it is, as long as it's some form of Y.Model.

Comment: Jonas is right. What matters is that you make a (single) call from the ModelList, and the call returns data representing some list of Models you need. So if your API supports pagination or search queries or whatever, that would be fine.